# Youtube Data API v3 limit reduced to 0

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are using YouTube Data API v3 in our production environment, all of a sudden today the Quota limit went to 0, we are now not able to make any API calls.

Is there any way to get at least the default limit of 1000. We have submitted the form to increase the quota but not sure how long it may take as our current users are not able to use our service.

Comment: No, there's no other way; you need to wait until Google reinstates your quota.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention if your application had gone through the verification process yet or not.   Assuming it has not you are given a short window of developer of quota to use during the development process.  If you have not verified your application in a timely manner. Then your quota will often be removed and set to 0

I have also seen developers whos quota gets set to 0 if they are doing something that was not verified in their original request.

You will need to request additional quota, it can take months in my experience three months to get a quota extension.